# How is the Prusa typical orange surface created?

Tags: prusa-i3, print-material, surface

Photos exist where the orange controller of Prusa printers is shown.

In most photos, it looks as if the surface is somewhat rough.

Here is such a photo:

[image]

It sparkles a bit, so I would assume that it's not perfectly even.

I do not own such a controller or Prusa printer, so I would like to ask if somebody could show a close up of what this surface really looks like and perhaps give me some information about how it could be re-created.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That texture you see is from the build surface, all prints you see are printed with the plane you see downwards.

There are several options to create such a surface finish. From texture coated heated beds to magnetic flexible build surfaces.

Comment: Thank you. I am a really newbie at this. I have a Kobra Max with 45 x 40 x 40 cm build size. Could you perhaps recommend a specific texture coated heated bed or build surface for that size? I actually really need 37 cm x 37 cm, so a smaller surface would not suit unfortunately.

Comment: @tmighty Smaller will always fit, larger sometimes!